# How to set value to variable using 'execute' in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(128) = 'myDb'
DECLARE @siteId int 
exec ('SELECT TOP 1 @siteId = Id FROM ' + @dbName + '..myTbl')  
select @siteId
```

When I run the script above I get the following error

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@siteId".

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Why and how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can use output parameters with sp_executesql.

```
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(128) = 'myDb'
DECLARE @siteId int 
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT TOP 1 @outputFromExec = Id FROM ' + quotename(@dbName) + N'..myTbl'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@outputFromExec int out', @siteId out
select @siteId
```

Comment: +1 This is the nicer way. I saw a parameterised database name and dismissed sp_executesql...

Comment: Cool, I found what I was looking for !

Comment: I am not able to use @siteId afterwards... it returns NULL.The execute line works fine...

Comment: @PauloHenrique Don't forget the final `OUT` in the `EXEC` line or it will fail silently.

Answer (score 28):

The dynamic SQL is a different scope to the outer, calling SQL: so @siteid is not recognised

You'll have to use a temp table/table variable outside of the dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(128) = 'myDb'
DECLARE @siteId TABLE (siteid int)

INSERT @siteId
exec ('SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM ' + @dbName + '..myTbl')  

select * FROM @siteId
```

Note: TOP without an ORDER BY is *meaningless*. There is no natural, implied or intrinsic ordering to a table. Any order is only guaranteed by the outermost ORDER BY

Comment: "TOP without an ORDER BY is meaningless" - Meaningless is probably a bit strong here, maybe all I want is 1 record and I don't care which, i.e. what restaurant should I eat at tonight?

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: maybe, but then there is no `ANY()` fucntion in SQL that gives arbitray rows. Otherwise I'd want my query to behave the same way every time instead of relying on some assumed order.

Comment: Your note just simply isn't true in most practical scenarios.  A ***maintained***, clustered index on the table will ensure a consistent, predictable order to the table results.

Comment: @Matt: do you maintain the clustered index after *every* update or insert that would result in fragmentation?

Comment: Time-dependent variables or proxies ensure that your ordering get implicitly maintained chronologically.  Your point can be a valid one, but the larger point of saying there is no "natural, implied or intrinsic ordering" is just not true, which was my point.  There is predictability in the physical storage location of a record, which translates to a time-dependent predictability in the `TOP` ordering.  Of course, this does not presuppose it's a useful order for a given query's purpose, but it is predictable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(100)
SET @ID = 4
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @Name = [Name]
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Department]
WHERE DepartmentID = @ID'
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@ID INT, @Name NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT',
@ID = @ID, @Name = @Name OUTPUT
SELECT @Name ReturnedName
```

Source : [blog.sqlauthority.com](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/11/20/sql-server-results-of-dynamic-sql-into-a-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Andrew Foster
-- Create date: 28 Mar 2013
-- Description: Allows the dynamic pull of any column value up to 255 chars from regUsers table
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.PullTableColumn
(
    @columnName varchar(255),
    @id int
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @columnVal TABLE (columnVal nvarchar(255));

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columnName + ' FROM regUsers WHERE id=' + CAST(@id AS varchar(10));
    INSERT @columnVal EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    SELECT * FROM @columnVal;
END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

A slight change in the execute query will solve the problem:

```
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(128) = 'myDb'
DECLARE @siteId int 
exec ('SELECT TOP 1 **''@siteId''** = Id FROM ' + @dbName + '..myTbl')  
select @siteId
```