# Why does EXEC retport an error of MUST DECLARE SCALAR VARIABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been struggling with the script bellow and I can't figure out a better way to do it.
Does anyone see the problem? I'm declaring the variable correctly.  Whys is it failing? Thanks for your help!

```
DECLARE @var1 as VarChar(50) 
DECLARE @var2 as VarChar(50) 

SET @Var1 = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'

EXEC('IF (select count(*) from Table1 where Column1 in (' + @Var1 + ')) = 5 
     SET @Var2 = ''True''
ELSE 
     SET @Var2 = ''False''')

SELECT @Var2
```

Error Message:

> MUST DECLARE SCALAR VARIABLE @Var2

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229070/how-to-set-value-to-variable-using-execute-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `sp_executesql` if you want to get values from parameters.

To shorten the query, use `CASE`.

```
DECLARE @var1 as VarChar(50) 
DECLARE @var2 as VarChar(50) 
SET @Var1 = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @Var = CASE WHEN count(*) = 5 THEN ''TRUE'' ELSE ''FALSE'' END FROM Table1 where Column1 IN (' + @Var1 + ')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@Var VARCHAR(5) OUTPUT', @Var=@var2 OUTPUT
SELECT @Var2
```

if you want to know if all `ID` from `@Var1` is present on the table, you also need to use `DISTINCT`

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @Var = CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT Column1) = 5 THEN ''TRUE'' ELSE ''FALSE'' END FROM Table1 where Column1 IN (' + @Var1 + ')'
```

- [sp_executesql <sup>MSDN Docs</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Since exec is executing dynamic part of SQL which is inside single quote. But @var2 is declared  outside exec. To solve this declare and select @var2 inside exec or use @var2 as set '+@var2+'

Answer (score 3):

Use sp_executeSQL instead of exec and use an output parameter

E.g. [How to get sp_executesql result into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

For example

```
DECLARE @var1 as VarChar(50) 
DECLARE @var2 as VarChar(50) 
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @Var1 = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Var2  VarChar(50) OUTPUT';

DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(500);

set @sSQL =  'IF (select count(*) from Table1 where Column1 in (' + @Var1 + ')) = 5 
     SET @Var2 = ''True''
ELSE 
     SET @Var2 = ''False'''

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @ParmDefinition, @Var2=@Var2 OUTPUT;

SELECT @Var2;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things there.. first where are the ";" ending the sentences. Also you need to scape the varchar values.

Agree with the other answer... use sp_executeSQL to run the dynamic sql.

An example of declare....

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @find varchar(30); 
/* Also allowed: 
DECLARE @find varchar(30) = 'Man%'; 
*/
SET @find = 'Man%'; 
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, ph.PhoneNumber
FROM Person.Person AS p 
JOIN Person.PersonPhone AS ph ON p.BusinessEntityID = ph.BusinessEntityID
WHERE LastName LIKE @find;
```

An example of sp_executeSQL..

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

/* Build the SQL string one time.*/
SET @SQLString =
     N'SELECT EmployeeID, NationalIDNumber, Title, ManagerID
       FROM AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee 
       WHERE ManagerID = @ManagerID';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ManagerID tinyint';
/* Execute the string with the first parameter value. */
SET @IntVariable = 197;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                      @ManagerID = @IntVariable;
/* Execute the same string with the second parameter value. */
SET @IntVariable = 109;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                      @ManagerID = @IntVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to stay away from executing sql strings.  I would rewrite this to be:

```
declare @cnt int

select @cnt = count(1) 
from Table1 
where Column1 in
    (select items
    from dbo.Split(@Var1,',')
    )

return @cnt   -- then the calling function says if this is true or false.
```

for the Split function see:  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999631/split-string-by-comma-in-sql-server-2008)