# Must declare the scalar variable "@Value"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the code below:

```
declare @value as nvarchar(100)
declare @sql as nvarchar(100)
set @Value = ' WHERE ID=@Value'

set @sql='SELECT * FROM person ' + @Value
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

The error I get is: Must declare the scalar variable "@Value".  Why is this?

Comment: Neither "duplicate" question is relevant to this one.  The first deals with parameterizing things that can't be parameterized (column access and table access).  As for the second, variable casing is a red herring here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamic SQL is executed separately, so the variables aren't available (set @Value = ' WHERE ID=@Value'), so you need to have sp_executesql declare them for itself.

What you can do is pass them in as follows:

`EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, '@Value nvarchar(100)', @Value = @Value;`

See also this question: [How to set value to variable using 'execute' in t-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229070/how-to-set-value-to-variable-using-execute-in-t-sql)

Comment: Are you sure about that`? TO my knowledge they are session based. Not having used dynamic SQL for years, but that soudns like a totally ok scenario for me.

Comment: Of course, that's the whole purpose for sp_executesql to take in parameter definitions.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx