# Why does my query throw incorrect syntax error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to run this query by it throws error when run i.e.

```
EXEC('Select Count(*) Total
      from '+@TableName+'
      where fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID='+ 'Cast('+@OrgID+' as varchar')
```

Why this error I get?

```
INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR VARCHAR
```

Note: `@TableName` is `Varchar(100)` and `@OrgID` is `int`

Comment: whats the @OrgID  value ?

Comment: Its just an ID that i am passing. Its datatype is INT

Comment: I hope that `fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID` is `int`? If so, why cast to varchar?

Answer (score 8):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in your call to `CAST`.  Try this:

```
EXEC('Select Count(*) AS Total from ' + @TableName +
     ' where fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID = Cast(' + @OrgID + ' as varchar)')
```

As @Felix pointed out, if your `fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID` column is already an `INT`, then there is no need to cast `@OrgID` to `VARCHAR`.  So just use the following:

```
EXEC('Select Count(*) AS Total from ' + @TableName +
     ' where fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID = ' + @OrgID)
```

Comment: I would add a suggestion to use `sp_executesql` instead.

Answer (score 4):

As others have answered, you forgot a `)` after the `VARCHAR`:

```
EXEC('Select Count(*) Total
      from '+@TableName+'
      where fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID='+ 'Cast('+@OrgID+' as varchar)');
```

However, I suggest not using `EXEC`. Instead you should use [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.105).aspx). This has an additional benefit of providing more security by preventing [**SQL Injection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
DECLARE @TableName  VARCHAR(100),
        @OrgID      INT;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = 
'SELECT COUNT(*) Total 
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
WHERE fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID = @OrgID';

EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql,
    N'@OrgID INT',
    @OrgID
;
```

*The above assumes that `fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID` is an `INT`.*

Further reading on dynamic SQL:

- [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) by Aaron Bertrand

Comment: If `fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID` is already an `INT` then why not use `fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID = @OrgId` directly and be done with it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you mean? That's exactly what I've done in my `sp_executesql` solution.

Comment: Yes, but in this case the original call to `EXEC` should also have worked, right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It still won't since you're concatenating a string (the query) with an int (the value of `@OrgID`).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I might be wrong though. SQL Server might implicitly convert the variable. This query is working: `DECLARE @id INT = 1;

EXEC ('SELECT * FROM(VALUES (1), (2)) t(Id) WHERE Id =' + @id);`

Comment: I think `EXEC` can work with variables, q.v. [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229070/how-to-set-value-to-variable-using-execute-in-t-sql).  But I'm sure you're right that there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, `EXEC` can work with variables. I'm just not sure why it's not producing a syntax error when you concatenate a string and int inside the `EXEC`, but the select errors out: `DECLARE @id INT = 1;

SELECT 'SELECT * FROM(VALUES (1), (2)) t(Id) WHERE Id =' + @id`

Answer (score 2):

In your query ")" is missing at last of CAST.

If @OrgID is defined varchar and fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID is int then you dont need to use CAST. Execute Following

```
EXEC('Select Count(*) Total
from '+@TableName+'
where fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID='+@OrgID)
```

If the column fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID is varchar type. Execute Following

```
EXEC('Select Count(*) Total
from '+@TableName+'
where fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID='''+@OrgID+'''')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing closing bracket

```
EXEC('Select Count(*) Total from '+ @TableName + ' where fk_Orgs_PropertyDetails_OrgID=' + 'Cast('+ @OrgID + ' as varchar)')
```