# SQL Server : select from exec using strings

Tags: sql-server

How to get output from exec (using strings) and assign it to a local variable?

Code:

```
declare @qry nvarchar(500)
declare @StateId nvarchar(10) 

set @qry= 'Select top 1 StateId FROM '+@TableName+' where '+@ColumnName+'='+str(@BusinessId)
exec(@qry)
```

I want

```
@StateID = exec(@qry)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set value to variable using 'execute' in t-sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229070/how-to-set-value-to-variable-using-execute-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @qry nvarchar(max) = 'select @id = id from ts_trails where id = 500'
declare @id nvarchaR(500)

exec sp_executesql @qry, N'@id int out', @id out

select @id
```

USE `sp_executesql` then make your variable the `output` parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one record:

```
 Declare @id int;
 select @id= column_id from yourtable
 select @id
```

This is passing data to variable

Comment: Then you can change from int to varchar